# Update site built by Tycho still contains erroneous dependency after re-build

Tags: maven, xtext, tycho

I have built an Eclipse update site with Tycho, but when trying to install a feature from it into target IDE fails.

The update site builds fine; I can see it from a target Eclipse installation and select the feature for installation.  However, the dependency check fails at start of install as it can't find a declared dependency (org.eclipselabs.xtext.utils.unittesting).  This shouldn't be a dependency: it was erroneously included in MANIFEST.MF for one of my eclipse plugin projects.

I removed the dependency from the manifest and run `mvn clean install` again. The build reported success, but when I try to use the newly built update site it still complains that the dependency to `org.eclipselabs.xtext.utils.unittesting` (a) exists and (b) can't be satisfied.

So the question is: **What else do I need to do to remove the dependency from the generated update site?**

Thanks for any pointers.

PS: I know I could add the site for o.e.x.u.unittesting in the target eclipse installation so it can satisfy the dependency.  However I don't want to do that; it's not needed for the feature to work and I don't want other users to have to add an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: **EDIT:** To be closed.  Deleting the dependency from the manifest is all that's required.  Problem was evidently caching of the feature description on host site and/or in eclipse.

Comment: The p2 director plugin is not relevant for this problem, is it? The "cannot satisfy dependency" problem occurs when you try to install from Eclipse, right?

Comment: Thanks @oberlies, question updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a list of cache locations that may have been involved in your scenario, and how to clear them

- *Target folder*: If the target folder contain results from a previous build, this data may be used by a Maven build to speed up the build. Tycho doesn't make use of this feature, and AFAIK it shouldn't pick up anything existing from the target folder.

  To be sure, always include the `clean` goal in your `mvn` calls.
- *Local Maven repository*: In order to support builds of parts of a reactor, Tycho adds artifacts that have been built locally with `mvn clean install` to the target platform. If you are not aware of this feature, this can have various strange effects.

  To avoid this, don't build with `install` unless you have to. Use `mvn clean verify` instead. Also: Deleting the file `~/.m2/repository/.meta/p2-local-metadata.properties` resets what Tycho considers to be "locally installed".

  Since Tycho 0.16.0, you can also disable this behaviour for one build through the command line switch `-Dtycho.localArtifacts=ignore` or for all builds by setting the same property in the settings.xml.
- *p2*: The p2 update manager in Eclipse caches p2 repositories it has used since the start of Eclipse.

  To force p2 to reload a repository, go to *Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites*, select a repository and hit *Reload*. The repositories will also be reloaded if you re-start Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late to the game, but I still want to share my experience.

I'm using [p2-maven-plugin](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin) to convert normal jar file to osgi bundle. It caches the converted jars in

```
~/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle
```

Unless I change the version of my jar, p2 plugin always load the old bundle from that location.

Delete the old bundle in that folder and rebuilt projects again solve my problem.